# Loop through unspecified folders for images in jekyll

Tags: image, jekyll

I have used this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34783367/1279102; but am unable to work out how to use a variable folder.

```
{% for image in site.static_files %}
    {% if image.path contains '{{ page.gallery }}' %}
        <img src="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ image.path }}" alt="image" />
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I have added 'gallery' to the front matter of my post. I have tried using the absolute path, and the relative path.

It appears that no matter how you add the `{{ page.gallery }}` variable in the `if` portion, it is **not** changed to the corrected value.

What am I missing?

Comment: How did you add gallery to the front matter? What if you try `{% if image.path contains page.gallery' %}`?

Comment: @marcanuy it'll work too.. but without the quotes

Comment: I tried both of these and both work. Thank you both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't interpolate within liquid tags.
assign the value to the variable beforehand.

```
{% capture ipath %}{{ page.gallery }}{% endcapture %}

{% for image in site.static_files %}
    {% if image.path contains ipath %}
        <img src="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ image.path }}" alt="image" />
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is working. But is there any way to exclude @2x files and show them in `srcset=""` property for constructing responsive images?